# How to deal with spam that contains my personal details?

Tags: email, spam, identity-management

I just noticed some spam in my inbox in GMail that is from a very suspicious e-mail address (partially redacted `anonymous@webXXXXXXX.ad.aruba.it`) containing a link to a similarly suspect URL (`http://centrodeesteticaopalo.com/URL_PARMS_REDACTED`).  The root website by itself returns an empty page (only newlines and line feeds) and I am not going to follow the actual link because it contains parameters which likely could identify me to the server.

Ordinarily I wouldn't even give such an e-mail the time of day and consider it to maybe be a phishing attempt, but what I find particularly disturbing is that the e-mail contains my real name and street address, along with the text "Your request was approved, you can become acquainted with the agreement here:" and a link to the above redacted link.

I'm assuming that some business I had given my personal information to was breached, but I'm not sure what action I should take, or even if there is anything I can or should do. Is it safe to ignore? Assume I have frozen my report with all three reporting agencies and there is nothing I don't recognize on any of my current reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your name, email address, and street address are not exactly secret information.  It's far more likely the data was either scraped, or purchased from some legitimate (or quasi-legitimate) source than stolen in a data breach.

In any case, regardless of whether it was purchased or stolen, yes, it's safe to ignore, or rather go ahead (since you're using Gmail) and report it as spam.  Then, forget about it.  If they could (and wanted to) use the data for identity theft, then they'd have gone ahead and done that rather than to waste their time sending you spam.